# How can I remove Cairo Dock from my desktop after having uninstalled it?

Tags: uninstall, cairo-dock

I have uninstalled Cairo Dock and now that I have done this, it is still attached to my desktop.

Every time I reboot the computer and sign in, a warning shows up on my desktop regarding my installation. I would like to get rid of it all together but I am not sure how.

It seems as though all is uninstalled except the toolbar. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please post the warning you get, and how you uninstalled CD to better see where your issue migth be.

Answer (score 5):

Try this command :

```
sudo apt-get purge cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Answer (score -2):

This will delete every package name start with word `cairo`:

`sudo apt-get remove --purge cairo*`

Comment: Please elaborate on what this command is supposed to do and how it will help to solve the problem.

Comment: Downvote because there are other unrelated packages with names starting with "cairo".